# Firebase remember me logic with token on react native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am building react native app and want to do remember me logic based on token
but can understand how to do it

my way was

```
const user = await fbRef.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword('gol@gmail.com', 'qwerty123');
console.log(user);
const token = await fbRef.auth().currentUser.getIdToken();
await AsyncStorage.setItem('AccessToken', token);
```

but i dont know how to do signin with this token ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add remember me function. Firebase Auth persists the user by default in react native using `asyncStorage`.

You need to wait for the state to be ready before you access `currentUser`:

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  // currentUser is ready now.
  if (user) {
    // User signed in. You can also access from firebase.auth().currentUser.
  } else {
    // User signed out.
  }
});
```

Comment: I have checked after reload of app firebase.auth().currentUser is null

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "reload of app". Have you implemented this check I added above?